# Python Mechanize not able to find specific form or control

Tags: authentication, mechanize

I'm trying to log in with python mechanize.

the form code is simple:  (i'm simplified it as well)

```
<form onsubmit="return(doSubmit());" action="/pkmslogin.form" method="post" name="frmLogin">
<input type="text" size="9" maxlength="128" value="" name="userid">
<input type="password" size="20" maxlength="46" value="" name="password">
<input type="submit" onclick="if (setReqURL()==false) return false; if (checkCookiesAtField(userid)) return true; else return false;" value=" OK " name="btnSubmit">
```

However, when I try to find form, or control elements i get controlnotfounderror.

input:

```
    for f in br.forms():     
        print f
```

output:

```
  <GET https://www.domain.com/pkmslogin.form application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(<None>=)>
  <TextControl(<None>=)>
  <TextControl(<None>=)>
  <TextControl(<None>=)>
  <TextControl(<None>=)>>
  <frmDummy GET https://www.domain.com/pkmslogin.form application/x-www-form>
```

When using FF Inspect Element or Firebug, it quite clearly shows the name of the first form as "loginform", with input boxes for "userid" and "password".

I have tried tirelessly to resolve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code as is..  very basic, but unsuccessful.   I have a feeling this will be a cookie issue.  But I'm not sure how this site builds cookies.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib2, urllib
    import requests
    import mechanize
    import cookielib
    import html2text
    import csv
    import sys, logging
    import time
    import os


    br = mechanize.Browser()

    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    # Browser options
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    # User-Agent 
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 ]

    br.open('https://www.domain.com/pkmslogin.form')
    time.sleep(2)
    br.select_form(nr=1)
    # br.form['userid'] = "****"
    # br.form['password'] = "************"
    #br.submit()
```

EDIT TO ADD:
on the login page:
if I:

```
sdata = br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
print soup
```

I get this for the form fields:

```
document.write("<td align=left><input type=\"text\" name=\"userid\" value=\"\" maxlength=\"128\" size=\"30\"></td>");
document.write("<td align=left><input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" value=\"\" maxlength=\"46\" size=\"30\">");
```

If that helps... hope it does..

Comment: Is there JavaScript in the page that modifies the page in the browser?  I know that in the original Perl WWW::Mechanize, you run into problems with JavaScript because WWW::Mechanize can't run JS.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that's what it was.  The form was rendered via JS into a table...  Sorry for the delay.. I ended up using vb and using 'raiseevent'

Comment: Also there was a "double redirect" that was causing probs.. and since the broswer wasnt visible, I was catching the page BEFORE redirect with the 'for f in br.forms()' statement..  so nothing there to review..  it was a fun test, and a great learning process..  I've now gotten pretty good at Python & Pearl and working on C# & VB (which is fantastic on the eyes comparatively)